# Need help automating IP list into file

Tags: perl

I have a config file that needs to import a list of IPs and display them like this

```
acl ip_1 myip 1.1.1.1
tcp_outgoing_address 1.1.1.1 ip_1

cl ip_2 myip 1.1.1.2
tcp_outgoing_address 1.1.1.2 ip_2

cl ip_2 myip 1.1.1.3
tcp_outgoing_address 1.1.1.3 ip_3
```

and so on.

I found this script but the problem with it is that it will only do ip_1 and ip_2. I have hundreds of IPs to import.

```
se strict;
use warnings;


open (my $tmph,"<", $ARGV[0]) or die "Error open file $ARGV[0]";

while (<$tmph>)
{
    chomp;
    my $line=$_;

 if ($line=~/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/)
    {
 print ("acl ip1 myip $line\n");
 print ("tcp_outgoing_address $line ip1\n\n");

 print ("acl ip2 myip $line\n");
 print ("tcp_outgoing_address $line ip2\n\n");
    }
}

close ($tmph);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to show what your actual file looks like.

Comment: use a variable and increment the variable in while body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code as follow

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $n = 1;

open (my $tmph,"<", $ARGV[0]) or die "Error open file $ARGV[0]";

while (<$tmph>)
{
    chomp;
    my $line=$_;

 if ($line=~/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/)
    {
         print ("acl ip$n myip $line\n");
         print ("tcp_outgoing_address $line ip$n\n\n");
         $n++;
    }
}

close ($tmph);
```

script output

```
perl do.pl ip.txt 
acl ip1 myip 1.2.3.4
tcp_outgoing_address 1.2.3.4 ip1

acl ip2 myip 10.0.0.10
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.10 ip2

acl ip3 myip 192.168.0.10
tcp_outgoing_address 192.168.0.10 ip3

acl ip4 myip 10.0.0.30
tcp_outgoing_address 10.0.0.30 ip4
```